# Using Laravel to average values, group by a category and a date range, and show the output on a single page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table that looks something like this:

[image: Sample Table]

I want to be able to query this table and display results based on grouping by *subject* and by *date*. The dates would satisfy a range (between x and y).

I am looking to output something like this:

> Term 1 - Art - (average of all asssessed_level for x range)
>
> Term 2 - Art - (average of all asssessed_level for y range)
>
> Term 3 - Art - (average of all asssessed_level for z range)

And this:

> Term 1 - Math - (average of all asssessed_level for x range)
>
> Term 2 - Math - (average of all asssessed_level for y range)
>
> Term 3 - Math - (average of all asssessed_level for z range)

(etc.)

If there is no assessed_level for a date range, then I still need it to return a subject with perhaps an 'N/A' for that spot.

Ultimately, I want a table of data that will look something like this:
[image: Resultant Example]

('E' would be where the average **assessed_level** goes and the **YEAR** column would be a result that is averaged and ignores the date range)

This is the code that I have written, but it doesn't provide the results that I need:

```
for($b=0; $b < $assessed_subjects->count(); $b++) {
    $assessment_strengths[] = DB::table('assessment_data')
        ->join('subjects', 'assessment_data.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
        ->join('units', 'assessment_data.unit_id', '=', 'units.id')
        ->join('outcomes', 'assessment_data.outcome_id', '=', 'outcomes.id')
        ->join('assessments', 'assessment_data.assessment_id', '=', 'assessments.id')
        ->select('subjects.short_name as subject_name', 'units.name as unit_name', 'outcomes.name as outcome_name', 'assessments.assessment_name as assessment_name', 'assessment_data.*')
        ->where('assessment_data.user_id', 28)
        ->where('assessment_data.student_id', $student_id)
        ->where('assessment_data.subject_id', $assessed_subjects[$b]->id)
        ->whereBetween('assessment_data.created_at', [$current_term->term_start, $current_term->term_end])
        ->orderBy('assessment_data.assessed_level', 'desc')
        ->get();
}
```

This is the output that I get when I dd() the query:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => Collection {#371 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  1 => Collection {#386 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  2 => Collection {#392 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#390 ▼
        +"subject_name": "Math"
        +"unit_name": "Rocks and Minerals"
        +"outcome_name": "Analyze how positive health habits can be supported by a variety of approaches to health practices and treatments"
        +"assessment_name": "The First Assessment"
        +"id": 36
        +"user_id": 28
        +"room_id": 1
        +"assessment_id": 1
        +"student_id": 6
        +"subject_id": 19
        +"unit_id": 188
        +"outcome_id": 476
        +"assessed_level": 4.0
        +"created_at": "2018-03-29 10:04:42"
        +"updated_at": "2018-03-29 10:04:42"
      }
    ]
  }
  3 => Collection {#399 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#397 ▼
        +"subject_name": "Social"
        +"unit_name": "Animals"
        +"outcome_name": "Demonstrate and explain the effect of adding zero to, or subtracting zero from, any number."
        +"assessment_name": "The First Assessment"
        +"id": 48
        +"user_id": 28
        +"room_id": 1
        +"assessment_id": 1
        +"student_id": 6
        +"subject_id": 25
        +"unit_id": 122
        +"outcome_id": 27
        +"assessed_level": 4.0
        +"created_at": "2018-01-01 10:04:42"
        +"updated_at": "2018-03-29 10:04:42"
      }
    ]
  }
  4 => Collection {#406 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  5 => Collection {#412 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  6 => Collection {#418 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#416 ▼
        +"subject_name": "ELA"
        +"unit_name": "Explore - Clarify and Extend"
        +"outcome_name": "State, orally in their own words, that in French the indefinite article is not used when identifying one’s profession (e.g., m. brown est dentiste.)"
        +"assessment_name": "The First Assessment"
        +"id": 18
        +"user_id": 28
        +"room_id": 1
        +"assessment_id": 1
        +"student_id": 6
        +"subject_id": 6
        +"unit_id": 25
        +"outcome_id": 3000
        +"assessed_level": 4.0
        +"created_at": "2018-03-29 10:04:42"
        +"updated_at": "2018-03-29 10:04:42"
      }
    ]
  }
  7 => Collection {#425 ▼
    #items: []
  }
]
```

As you can see, there are empty values (0, 1, 4, 5, 7) that I would like to push some data to. I took a look at IFNULL and COALESCE as a way of providing a fall-back, but that wasn't helpful in this case. Is there a way to append (or something like that) values into query results, even if they are otherwise empty?

My thought process is that if I can define each of the records that are being output as belonging to a specific term, I will be closer to having what I need.

Comment: That's a pretty serious query for us to try and understand. What problem does it have in more specific terms?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I never quite know how to detail out what I need on here (which is a part of my problem)! I will update my questions with some more specifics.

Comment: With a query of that complexity I'd guess you're pretty close, so if you can explain what it'd take to push that over the finish line it'd help. Often with joins it's a case of not including the right data, or `RIGHT` vs. `LEFT` issues.

Comment: I just added a bit more info, @tadman. Let me know if that's at all clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an approach like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach($assessed_subjects as $subject) {
    $query = DB::table('assessment_data')
        ->select(DB::raw('avg(`assessed_level`) as `avg`'))
        ->where('user_id', 28)
        ->where('student_id', $student_id)
        ->where('subject_id', $subject->subject_id);
    foreach($user_terms as $term) {
        $result[$subject->subject_id][$term->id] = (clone $query)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$term->term_start, $term->term_end])
            ->first()->avg;
    }
    $result[$subject->subject_id]['year'] = (clone $query)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$user_terms->first()->term_start, $user_terms->last()->term_end])
        ->first()->avg;
}
```

This gives you the average level grouped by subject and term. If there is no value, it's `NULL`.

Or an alternative solution with fewer queries:

```
$result = [];
$query = DB::table('assessment_data')
    ->select('subject_id', DB::raw('avg(`assessed_level`) as `avg`'))
    ->where('user_id', 28)
    ->where('student_id', $student_id)
    ->whereIn('subject_id', $assessed_subjects->pluck('subject_id'))
    ->groupBy('subject_id');
foreach($user_terms as $term) {
    $rows = (clone $query)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$term->term_start, $term->term_end])
        ->get();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $result[$row->subject_id][$term->id] = $row->avg;
    }
}
$rows = (clone $query)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$user_terms->first()->term_start, $user_terms->last()->term_end])
    ->get();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $result[$row->subject_id]['year'] = $row->avg;
}
```

The only disadvantage is that it doesn't add `NULL` values for missing averages to the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The average would be the average of all assessments for a subject (or it could be an average of all the terms, whichever is easier to program). A *year* is a school year, not a calendar year (typically September - June).

Comment: So from the start of term 1 until the end of term 3?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Each teacher is free to establish their own Term start and end dates, up to a maximum of 12 terms in a school year. (This is where the $term->term_start and $term->term_end are pulling the data from as the loop iterates over each term that the user has established.) Let me know if you have any other questions. :)

Comment: Let me get back to you shortly after I've taken the code for a spin.

Comment: I think this may work, but I will have to take a good look at it in the morning. I was able to enter it in as-is (with a modification on the spelling of 'assessed_level' and a change from '$term' to '$user_terms' and I am getting a results array. Just need to sift through it and tweak it a little to see if this is what I need. Thanks so much for your help. I'll get back to you again.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was able to tweak a couple things in the query to reflect some of the data that I needed to reference (primarily from **$subject->id** to **$subject->subject_id**) and it is looking promising. Still some finagling to do, but I believe this is the right path. And thank you for teaching me about **clone**!

Comment: One question: you are using **->first(['avg'])->avg** — is there a way to use **->get()** instead of just first? The data being pulled is only the first record and I need to average out all records for a subject within a term. I tried changing it to get() but it produced *"HigherOrderCollectionProxy"* (which I have never seen before).

Comment: So I don't flood this area with back-and-forth comments, here is an example of the database 'assessment_data': http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95a00d0/1

Comment: Using `->get()` is not necessary because the query only returns one row with one "column": the average level of all records for the given subject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168570/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-sheldon-scott).